# VLOOKUP function to modify column data

Tags: string, excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup

I have some data, say selected IDs, in sheet A. Sheet B contains all the data and I use VLOOKUP to filter the rows in sheet B based on IDs in sheet A. I want to know if I can change the data in any column of that filtered rows. Say I have a data with ID 10:

```
10   0002345678
```

I want to change the corresponding data against this ID by adding a "$" instead of one zero so record length doesn't change:

```
10   00$2345678
```

I have a lot of entries and want to automate this process.

Can we use the REPLACE function as a parameter in the VLOOKUP, or any other solution like using VBA?

Comment: Is it always the third character you'll be changing?

Comment: It depends, but record length will remain same. Last zero has to be replaced by a special character.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are asking whether possible "on the fly" to which the answer would be yes. For example:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(A1,A!A:B,2,0),"000","00$")
```

---

If to replace last `0` with `$` the following adaptation may suit:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(A1,A!A:B,2,0),0,"$",LEN(VLOOKUP(A1,A!A:B,2,0))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(A1,A!A:B,2,0),0,"")))
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. This approach should work for me if instead of fixed data we can use generic column value name for finding an replacing data. I guess I should use replace function?